# C++, Segfault when catching error as refernce

Tags: c++, exception, segmentation-fault

when I catch any exception as a reference and try to access it with e.what(), I get an Segfault. Does anyone have an idea, why this happens?

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    try{
        throw ::std::runtime_error("test");
    }catch(::std::exception const &e){
        ::std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

I get:

```
 bash: line 1: 22110 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) 'test' < /dev/null > 'test.stdout' 2> 'test.stderr'
```

With ASAN I get:

```
ASAN:SIGSEGV
=================================================================
==21318==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x2af35c5534bf bp 0x7ffc1b30ee30 sp 0x7ffc1b30ee10 T0)
    #0 0x2af35c5534be  (/media/psf/Home/test+0xf54be)
    #1 0x2af35ebf4ec4  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21ec4)
    #2 0x2af35c4a68a6  (/media/psf/Home/test+0x488a6)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==21318==ABORTING
```

I use: Ubuntu clang version 3.6.0-2ubuntu1~trusty1 (tags/RELEASE_360/final) (based on LLVM 3.6.0)

on: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS,Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-76-generic #120-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Solution: Deleting -lc++abi solved the problem for me.

Comment: You should catch by `const &`

Comment: @NathanOliver This does not change anything

Comment: Can' reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/809d04ff6316a8cc

Comment: On a side note, leading double colon is not needed here, and is just syntax noise. Get rid of it.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes this does just occur on my system but on none of the other systems I tried...

Comment: can you try without the input and output stream redirections ?

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Comment: What's your compile/link command? Are you sure there is no C++ runtime library misconfiguration? What does ldd tell you for the executable you build?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker The same error occurs if I try to do std::string mystring(e.what());

Comment: Not just _which_ compiler, but what's the actual command line you're using? Also, are you compiling it on the same machine on which you're running it?

Comment: I still do not see compiler/linker command line.

Comment: are you sure you're running your program and not the standard `test` tool ? Try using `./test` instead (and also remove the quotes).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker As you can see from his ASAN input, he's running his program.

Comment: @YamMarcovic : ah yes - missed that. Then I'd still like to see it run without the stream redirections (ie. not just remove the output from the code, but remove the redirection from the command line). If that doesn't help, we'll need to dive into how exactly it was built - as was requested before.

Comment: @SergeyA Thank you very much for the idea with the compiler flags. I use a lot of Flags, but actually deleting -lc++abi solved the problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver it should work whether or not catching by const reference

Comment: @xrockx you should not edit solutions into the question; instead post as an answer.

Comment: @M.M Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. I added it. Thank you for the information. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Deleting the compiler flag -lc++abi solved the problem for me.